# JavaFX Binding entire model to form

Tags: javafx, binding, model

I spent full day to make my model observable by this JavaFx databinding.
At this point I already see, that if I change one property like this, it works like charm

```
selectedTestcase.setFolder("....");
```

but how I can observe the following and refresh my form:

```
if (maybeCase.isPresent()) {
        selectedTestcase = maybeCase.get();
}
```

So I change the complete model. How I can make this?

**Model:**

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Testcase")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PROPERTY)
public class Testcase {

private StringProperty Guid;
@XmlElement(name="GUID")
public String getGuid() {
    return guidProperty().get();
}
public StringProperty guidProperty() {
    if (Guid == null)
        Guid = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "Guid");
    return Guid;
}
public void setGuid(String guid) {
    this.guidProperty().set(guid);
}

private StringProperty caseName;
@XmlElement(name="CaseName")
public String getCaseName() {
    return caseNameProperty().get();
}
public StringProperty caseNameProperty() {
    if (caseName == null)
        caseName = new SimpleStringProperty();
    return caseName;
}
public void setCaseName(String caseName) {
    this.caseNameProperty().set(caseName);
}
```

**ViewModel:**

```
public Testcase selectedTestcase = new Testcase();

public void setSelectedTestcase(String folder, String filename) {

    Optional<Testcase> maybeCase = this.AvailableTestCases.stream()
            .filter((t -> t.TestcaseEqualsFolderAndName(folder, filename))).findFirst();

    if (maybeCase.isPresent()) {
        selectedTestcase = maybeCase.get();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Have a look at Tomas Mikula's [EasyBind](https://github.com/TomasMikula/EasyBind) framework - in particular [`MonadicObservableValue`s](http://tomasmikula.github.io/blog/2014/03/26/monadic-operations-on-observablevalue.html), which is exactly what you are needing here. He expands on this functionality in his [ReactFX framework](https://github.com/TomasMikula/ReactFX)

Comment: I can't see how to use it for make possible to bind a whole model..

Comment: Start with `ObjectProperty<TestCase> maybeProperty = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(...);` where the value may be null. Then do `MonadicObservableValue<TestCase> maybeCase = EasyBind.monadic(maybeProperty);`. Then you can do things like `label.textProperty().bind(maybeCase.flatMap(TestCase::guidProperty).orElse(""));`.

Comment: I have not an possible null property.

Comment: So why are you wrapping your current `maybeCase` in an `Optional`, if it might not be null??? Probably you have to elaborate on your question to make it clearer what you are trying to do.

Comment: its just to prevent possible wrong filenames at input (programm get accessed by an chrome extension // webrequest..) I just like to do oldmodel = newModel,

Comment: So then it *is* possible it would be null?

Comment: Yes but its not what I care for..

Comment: So then you would use the code I posted in the previous comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to James_D and the Easybind Library:

[MonadicObservableValue](http://tomasmikula.github.io/blog/2014/03/26/monadic-operations-on-observablevalue.html)

That seems to be the solution:

```
private ObjectProperty<Testcase> testcaseObjectProperty = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(new Testcase());

public MonadicObservableValue<Testcase> selectedTestcase = EasyBind.monadic(testcaseObjectProperty);

public void setSelectedTestcase(String folder, String filename) {

    Optional<Testcase> maybeCase = this.AvailableTestCases.stream()
            .filter((t -> t.TestcaseEqualsFolderAndName(folder, filename))).findFirst();

    if (maybeCase.isPresent()) {
        testcaseObjectProperty.setValue(maybeCase.get());
    }
}
```

and then the final binding:

```
txtCaseName.textProperty().bind(viewModel.selectedTestcase.flatMap(Testcase::caseNameProperty).orElse(""));
```

James; you are able to explain me this "orElse"?

Comment: `MonadicObservableValue` just behaves like an observable `Optional`. `flatMap` maps to another `MonadicObservableValue` as follows: if `selectedTestCase` is empty, it returns an empty `MonadicObservableValue`, otherwise it returns a `MonadicObservableValue` which contains the result of applying the specified function to the value contained by `selectedTestCase`. So `selectedTestCase.flatMap(...)` is a `MonadicObservableValue<String>`. Calling `orElse("")` results in an `ObservableValue` that contains `""` if its empty, or the original contained value if not. (Just like `Optional.orElse(...)`.)

Comment: James, like I see it, its not an bidirectional binding; is there a possibility too?

Comment: Bidirectional binding is a bit problematic. Suppose `selectedTestCase` is empty (i.e. wraps null), so then `txtCaseName.getText()` would be `""` by the binding. If you then change the text in `txtCaseName`, what should happen with a bidirectional binding? The binding would somehow need to create a new `Testcase` instance with `caseName` set to the new text, and in general there's no unique (or even canonical) way to do that. Having said that, I think the ReactFX framework does this (somehow) with `Var` [see here](http://tomasmikula.github.io/blog/2015/02/10/val-a-better-observablevalue.html)).

Comment: [link] (Whats about this? Here bidirectionial binding works..)

Comment: [http://pastebin.com/U72aFbRV] (Whats about this? Here bidirectionial binding works..)